Storing a cookie from urlParams and getting cookie to store in a variable
I am getting a url parameter (referrer) and then setting it as a cookie - this works great.
I then want to retrieve the cookie value into a variable and then set the cookie value into the innerHTML and value of an input box. - this code (the retrieveReferrer function seems to do nothing).
Where am I going wrong? and is their a tidier, simpler way to achieve all of this?
const queryString = window.location.search;
if(queryString.length > 0) {
   const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(queryString);
   const referrerID = urlParams.get('referrer');
   setCookie('referrerID', referrerID, 1);
}

// Set a Cookie
function setCookie(cName, cValue, expDays) {
    let date = new Date();
    date.setTime(date.getTime() + (expDays * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
    const expires = "expires=" + date.toUTCString();
    document.cookie = cName + "=" + cValue + "; " + expires + "; path=/"; 

}

function retrieveReferrer() {
   var StoredReferrer = getCookie("referrerID");
   console.log(StoredReferrer)
   var divElem = document.querySelector(".booking-referrer .el-input__inner").innerHTML = StoredReferrer;
   var divElem2 = document.querySelector(".booking-referrer .el-input__inner").value = StoredReferrer; 
}


Are you sure retrieveReferrer() is being called? Please post a [mre].

DIV elements don't have a .value. That's only for elements that get user input.

Do you see the console.log() output?
